# Wix resource harvesting tool "Heat". How to harvest files with dynamic name like Microsoft run time files generated on build

Tags: c#, azure-devops, wix, heat, harvest

I have really simple issue but seems I can't find answer easily due Wix restrictions, also to mention I am pretty new to Wix.

Problem is, as described in title, I can't make heat harvest couple of files that are generated on build and name of those files are changed based on OS run time (precisely .Net Core) other then going manually to product.wix file and changing name of couple of resources.

File example

```
\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64\PubTmp\Out\mscordaccore_amd64_amd64_4.6.28207.03.dll".
```

Version 4.6.28207.03.dll is dynamical generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a try harvesting the [outputs of your vs project](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html), since the dll files are the output of your project.

`heat project "MyProject.csproj" -pog:Binaries -ag -template:fragment -out project.wxs`

And you can also try adding a post-build event on your main application project to copy those files in a special location and have the Heat.exe read them from there. You can refer to this blog [here](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/2010/02/23/wix-3-tutorial-generating-filedirectory-fragments-with-heat.exe/).

In azure devops pipeline, You can try adding a [copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy those files to a specific location where Heat can read from.

Comment: I had idea to write pre build step and run script to harvest files. But in that case i still have issue on updating my Product.wxs and ProductFolderStructure.wxs. That would also be some scripting which is not an easy solution since i need to insert and change Component arguments such Source, ID... But i see from all the research there is no easier way